# Why isn't the virtual keyboard closed properly

Tags: android, window, virtual-keyboard

---

I'm running a program which is calling a `mmSocket.connect()` -procedure in which a bluetooth pairing-process is started. If the phones aren't paired a dialog shows up after the code is entered on the device I want to connect with.

[image]

Sometimes the connection breaks and the dialog is terminated leaving the keyboard visual in the background.

[image]

Haven't found a way to close that keyboard. Have already tried the following:

- `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`
  which should work if you ask me...

As always, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now listed as a bug, please see the following link for info:

[Google Code issue - 18911](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18911&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the keyboard with the following code:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(triggeringView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

where triggeringView is the view that has shown the keyboard

Comment: How do I get the view when all I did was call `connect()`?, The dialog is created from a system call

Comment: Posted it as a bug [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18911&q=bluetooth&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)